# How to initialise a variable with a specific domain of numbers in MiniZinc?

Tags: minizinc

In MiniZinc, we initialise a domain of values using for example:

var 2..6: X;

However, if the values required are only [2, 4, 6] excluding 3 and 5, how does one initialise such a domain for the variable?

Comment: Could you initialize `var 1..3: X;` and then multiply by `2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the set notation `{...}` to enumerate the valid domain, i.e. curly braces, not brackets.

```
var {2,4,6}: x;
```

Note: `2..6` is the same as (or rather a shorthand of) `{2,3,4,5,6}`.

This is discussed a little more in the [MiniZinc Tutorial](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.3/en/modelling.html).